# Два проекта Laravel - один OpenServer

Tags: php, laravel, curl

Всем здравствуйте. Не могу никак решить проблему с двумя отдельными проектами Laravel: с первого проекта идёт запрос к другому -

```
$url = "http://api.site";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Второй должен вернуть следующее:

```
return response()->json([
       'app' => env('APP_NAME'),
       'database' => env('DB_DATABASE')
    ]);
```

Но - возвращается `env` первого проекта, а не второго. В чём может быть проблема? Всю голову изломал.

P.S. Проекты новые и чистые, ничего не менялось. Домены в OpenServer настроены. При выполнении `curl` из-под не `Laravel`, то-есть просто отдельный файл скрипта, всё работает верно.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов, это точно дубль.

Answer (score 0):

Это [php bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71607). 
Так происходит потому, что подзапрос, сделанный из первого приложения, все еще находится в том же процессе (по сути, конфигурация кешируется).